# IntelliJ IDEA git Permission denied (publickey)

Tags: windows, git, intellij-idea, ssh

I got a strange problem with using git on IntelliJ IDEA on Windows 10.
If I want to access the remote repo on GitLab, I always get
[Permission denied (publickey)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dEPMK.png).
Everything I found here or via Google didn't solve the problem.
I tried:

1. Setting the ssh executable to Native
2. Converting my public key from Putty to ssh-keygen style
3. Removing known_hosts

I also tried to access the repo with [Git Bash](https://git-for-windows.github.io/), it works fine like that. 
Another interesting fact is that after removing known_hosts, I got "Host key verification failed". I had to use Git Bash once to recreate the known_hosts entry, after that I got the Permission denied error again. Somehow I don't get asked for any user input.

Comment: The very same thing happens to me.

Comment: Can you post exactly the commands you did in git bash?

Comment: And where are you keys located?

Comment: Sorry, this is too long ago, i can't remember the commands. The keys where located in C:/Users/<name>/.ssh/git and I used a config entry for the host to tell ssh to use that key.
I can just tell you that it works right now under Ubuntu 18.04 with Intellij 2018.3.3. I don't use Windows anymore.

Answer (score 62):

I faced this problem while connecting bitbucket cloud from my Intellij 2019.2 , which thankfully got solved with the following steps. Please note that these steps are to be carried out after you successfully generate and add ssh-public key to your bitbucket/github/gitlab profile.

1. Open Git-SCM **ssh_config** file present in Git-SCM installation directory.It's default location in Windows (for 64 bit) is in C:\Program Files\Git\etc\ssh\
2. Add the following lines into ssh_config

```
Host *your-gitlab-or-github-or-bitbucket-hostname*
     IdentityFile *your-ssh-rsa-privatekey-file-with-absolute-path*
```

for e.g

```
Host bitbucket.org
     IdentityFile C:/Users/Sahil/.ssh/id_rsa
```

Source:
https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/360004124959-IntelliJ-2019-1-3-Can-t-access-git-using-SSH-keys

Comment: Even on Windows you can configure the IdentityFile as `~/.ssh/id_rsa` which equals to `%USERPROFILE%\.ssh\id_rsa`.
*To create the rsa file run PuttyGen, open your private key, from menu use Conversions - Export OpenSSH key and save it as `%USERPROFILE%\.ssh\id_rsa`.*

Comment: Can confirm this works on Win10 with Intellij IDEA 2020.3. Doesn't even need to restart the IDE. Might need administrator permission on editing the file.

Comment: This is the way! Just spent half an hour trying to figure this out. So many outdated answers everywhere. Don't forget to point to the key in **openssh** format, otherwise it will complain about format.

Comment: This works on win10 in Clion 2022.2, tnx!

Comment: I am using WSL2. If your source code is located in /var/www, you need to copy the id_rsa file into WSL as well by using this command: `sudo cp /mnt/c/Users/Admin/.ssh/id_rsa ~/.ssh/`

Answer (score 6):

### Update IDEA 2021.2.3

The bug in Sahil's answer has been fixed and Christian's solution is not needed with the correct entry in your ssh config file for the most common case of one key for one or more hosts. Additional options for complex configurations, such as multiple keys to the same or multiple hosts, can be found [in Maddes comprehensive answer on superuser](https://superuser.com/questions/232373/how-to-tell-git-which-private-key-to-use).

**ANY inconsistency between ssh-agent and ssh-add leads to a situation where some things work and some don't.**

For example, I had the Windows OpenSSH agent running but my path pointed first to the Git for Windows `ssh-add`. Many such failures are possible given the many ssh implementations out there, so *know that you know* where things are running from.

To get ssh working in IDEA...

---

**Git for Windows**

1. Install Git for Windows. I put it in C:\Git since, as a standard user without an elevated install, I couldn't write to `C:\Program Files`.
2. In `Control Panel | User Accounts | Change my environment variables` add the Git `usr\bin` folder to the path after the `cmd` folder entry already there (e.g. `C:\Git\usr\bin` for my installation).
3. **Unset environment variable HOME** -- it still breaks ssh in this version of IDEA.
4. In a Windows cmd.exe console, run start-ssh-agent.cmd to start the agent
5. In IDEA in `Settings | SSH Configurations | Authentication type:` set it to `Key pair OpenSSH or PuTTY` and test your connection. Then, make a small change and test `Commit and push...`.

---

**Windows OpenSSH**

1. In `Control Panel | User Accounts | Change my environment variables` add `C:\Windows\System32\OpenSSH` to your path. *Make sure no other ssh implementation is ahead of this in the path!*
2. Start the OpenSSH agent in `Task Manager | Services` (or any number of other ways)
3. Set your IDEA `SSH Configuration` as #5 above

---

Keep in mind that, on Windows, ssh in IDEA uses the environment available in a standard Windows command-line console (cmd.exe). If git operations work there, then with the above steps in place, they'll work in IntelliJ.

Comment: Step #5 was the key (ho ho) for me using PyCharm 2020.3.3 on Linux

Answer (score 4):

It has been really long since OP but here is my solution on an execution basis:

1. You need to open a prompt and set the ENVVAR `GIT_SSH_COMMAND`.
2. You need to open IntelliJ from that same prompt.

Example:

```
> set GIT_SSH_COMMAND=ssh -i C:\\path\\to\\not\\default\\key
> idea
```

Also the path to not-default-key should use `~` instead of %userprofile% or paths unix-like using `/`.

Answer (score 1):

I was having this same issue, and while it did have to do with the public key, my issue was concerned with WSL2/Linux and windows .ssh folders. My keys were in my WSL2/linux folder system, but intelliJ was looking in my windows folder system.

I copied my rsa keys from WSL2 to windows, and it worked automatically. In fact, I attempted to have it fail again by removing the keys from the Windows folders, but intelliJ must have it's own keylocker solution, because even without the keys in the Windows .ssh folder intelliJ continued to work.

For a screen capture explaining it you can see it here https://vimeo.com/558267383/74d55415c4

Answer (score 0):

If you're using wsl2 in Clion like me, just add

```
Host github.com
        IdentityFile /home/yieatn/.ssh/github
```

to /home/user/.ssh/config (create if it doesn't exit). You don't even have to restart IDE.

Answer (score 0):

Adding to *Cristian Torres*'s answer:

For all of you folks struggling with a similar problem on **Mac OSX**:

1. In IntelliJ, PyCharm, etc. click `Tools -> Create Command-line Launcher...`
2. Open your terminal and execute:

```
$ export GIT_SSH_COMMAND="ssh -i ~/.ssh/your-custom-private-key"
$ idea
```

> For PyCharm the executable name is `charm` or `/usr/local/bin/charm`
>
> Goland: `goland` or `/usr/local/bin/goland`
>
> WebStorm: `webstorm` or `/usr/local/bin/webstorm`

Answer (score 0):

On Windows 11, a fresh install (no Putty or anything, just the built-in OpenSSH server that is in the Optional Features of Windows).  First add your keys:

```
ssh-add c:\work\gitlabKey c:\work\githubKey
ssh-add -l  #this will verify the keys were added
```

If you get an error that the agent isn't running, it's a Windows Service that you need to enable and set to start-up on boot -- do this in Powershell:

```
Set-Service   ssh-agent -StartupType Automatic
Start-Service ssh-agent
```

Once the keys are added, PHPstorm still wasn't using them to connect when I tried to create a new project. So adding this to my `Environment Variables` did the trick (reboot may be required)

```
name=GIT_SSH
value=C:\windows\System32\OpenSSH\ssh.exe
```

(you will need to restart your IDE or possibly computer)

If you see this error `Clone failed: CreateProcessW failed...Host key verification failed` then open your Terminal and do a manual connection to the site first

```
ssh -T git@github.com
```

[image: SSH]